# Is there a difference in wavelength emission spectra of ZnS:Ag when its irradiated with protons vs. gammas?

Tags: photons, spectroscopy, wavelength, protons, gamma-rays

How would I measure this, because I couldn't find this information in literature as of yet? I have neutron (to produce protons by recoil) and gamma sources, but I don't have a pure neutron source, and I have only a x-ray generating spectrophotometer.

Comment: Generally speaking, yes, the response of a semiconductor to gamma (electron) vs heavy particle (n, p, $\alpha$, etc.). Gamma/electron makes mainly isolated point defects, the heavier particles can result in defect clusters. This has been an observed feature since the early days of rad effects. Also note that protons and neutrons will not be the same (different recoil energy distribution). And it will be much easier to find somebody with a proton accelerator than make lots of protons through (n,p) reactions.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster! My crystal with PMT vs. SiPM is giving vastly different results, to elaborate, the SiPM detects a lot less gammas than PMT. COuld you point me towards literature that discusses such differences as in your last comment? It would be highly useful for my work.

Comment: A classic reference would be Messenger and Ash, 'The Effects of Radiation on Electronic Systems (1986). IEEE Transactions on Nuclear Science has many papers.